# При использовании модуля Heatmap в Яндекс.картах подавляется вывод ошибок

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, heatmap

Возникла проблема, что при использовании модуля Heatmap, подавляется вывод ошибок в консоль браузера. Исследовав исходник https://github.com/yandex/mapsapi-heatmap/blob/master/build/heatmap.js, ничего подозрительного не нашел. Однако код вида:

```
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=RU_ru&amp;apikey=ключ" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://yastatic.net/s3/mapsapi-jslibs/heatmap/0.0.1/heatmap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map" style="height: 300px;width: 300px;"></div>
<script>
ymaps.ready(['Heatmap']).then(function init() {
    latitude=59.2084992;
    longitude=39.8491648;
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [latitude, longitude],        
        zoom: 7,
    });
    console.log("1");          
        abrakadabra(); // Вот здесь должно выкинуть ошибку, т.к. такой функции НЕТ!!!
    console.log("2");          
});  
</script>
```

Выполняется ровно до вызова не существующей функции abrakadabra() и останавливается, не выводя в консоль сообщения об ошибке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема исчезает, если убрать модуль Heatmap, и вывод сообщений начинает работать штатно.

Я что-то не догоняю, почему так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось это асинхронная функция, и вывод ошибок перехватывается при помощи catch (console.log). В итоге код должен выглядеть так:

```
ymaps.ready(['Heatmap']).then(function init() {
    console.log("1");          
        abrakadabra(); // Вот здесь должно выкинуть ошибку, т.к. такой функции НЕТ!!!
    console.log("2");          
}).catch (console.log);
```